# Jenkins and powershell treat (data) as a cmdlet

Tags: powershell, jenkins

I have a Jenkins pipeline that uses a bat command to run a powershell script, which passes in some text from a Jenkinsfile.

I have the param in my Jenkinsfile:

```
daLogNames="Copy Verivo Deployables (data) to Application Directory"
```

A powershell script using that parameter is called:

```
bat "powershell -nologo ./getLogFile.ps1  ${SERENA_TOKEN} ${pipelineParams.daLogNames}  %WORKSPACE%/${env.EV_DA_APPNAME}.json"
```

The Jenkins build is failing because of the following message:

```
    data : The term 'data' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, 
script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path 
was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:72
+ ./getLogFile.ps1 **** Copy Verivo Deployables (data) 
to  ...
+                                                                        ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (data:String) [], CommandNotFoun 
   dException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

How can I pass (data) without it throwing an error? Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: `${pipelineParams.daLogNames}` -> `""${pipelineParams.daLogNames}""`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This text: `daLogNames="Copy Verivo Deployables (data) to Application Directory"` is being put directly in your bat, so it ends up like:

```
powershell -nologo ./getLogFile.ps1 SERENA_TOKEN Copy Verivo Deployables (data) to Application Directory c:/workspace/APPNAME.json
```

And the `(data)` part is being read as an expression, as if you had written:

```
write-host 1 + 1 is (1+1)
```

where the thing in `()` is evaluated. But it can't find `data` as a thing to run, and throws an error.

As Mathias R. Jessen comments, the fix is to quote all that text, so it gets passed as a single string parameter to your PowerShell script, e.g.

```
bat "powershell -nologo ./getLogFile.ps1  ${SERENA_TOKEN} ""${pipelineParams.daLogNames}""  %WORKSPACE%/${env.EV_DA_APPNAME}.json"
```

or maybe:

```
bat "powershell -nologo ./getLogFile.ps1  ${SERENA_TOKEN} '${pipelineParams.daLogNames}' %WORKSPACE%/${env.EV_DA_APPNAME}.json"
```